# Getting weird characters (Chinese) when reading csv files with LibrOffice

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I remember one of my colleagues sent me a csv file to check it.
I opened it using LibrOffice, it was too big so I had problems and could not open it (but I could open it using google docs on google drive).
After that, whenever I open a csv file, I get this:
[image]

I don't know where the Chinese characters came from! But I can't get rid of them.

when any csv file is opened, I get this:
[image]

And I am asked to download additional fonts. when I agree, I find no fonts to download.
I also tried to uninstall LibreOffice and install it again:

```
sudo apt-get purge fonts-opensymbol libreoffice libreoffice-\* openoffice.org-dtd-officedocument1.0 python\*-uno uno-libs3-\* ure ure-dbg
sudo apt-get -s purge fonts-opensymbol libreoffice libreoffice-\* openoffice.org-dtd-officedocument1.0 python\*-uno uno-libs3-\* ure ure-dbg
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

But it didn't work!
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your character-set is UTF-16. I think you use a wrong charset. Probably UTF-8 is the right one. Or the csv file uses Big Endian (UTF-16 BE) and you Little Endian (UTF-16 LE) or the other way round. Try some different charsets and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't pay attention to that since I don't remember that I changed it.
Now I changed it to utf-8 and it works.

Comment: i'm on windows, and on vscode, i open the csv it looks normal, then save it to utf-16 BE, re open on libre, IT WORKS!!! thank you!